# How do I use jtracert to analyse an application running on Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, sequence-diagram, jtracert

I'd like to generate sequence diagrams of a running java ee application using [jtracert](http://code.google.com/p/jtracert/).  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "Quick Start" chapter on the project main page: http://code.google.com/p/jtracert/

In a few words:
   1. Install SDEdit (it's absolutely free) http://sdedit.sourceforge.net/
   2. Open SDEdit
   3. Choose Item Start/stop RT server in menu Extras
   4. Enter any port you like and press ok
   5. Add the following parameters to your application startup: -DanalyzerOutput=sdEditRtClient -DsdEditHost=127.0.0.1 -DsdEditPort=60001 -javaagent:jTracert.jar

The place where you should specify these parameters depends on your application server.

A few examples are stated below. Please note that you should replace jTracert.jar with real jar name, like jTracert-0.0.3.jar!

**WebLogic 9+**

Windows

File: %DOMAIN_HOME%\bin\startWeblogic.cmd.
Add the following line:

set JAVA_OPTIONS=-DanalyzerOutput=sdEditRtClient -DsdEditHost=127.0.0.1 -DsdEditPort=60001 -javaagent:jTracert.jar %JAVA_OPTIONS%

Linux

File: $DOMAIN_HOME\bin\startWeblogic.sh.
Add the following line:

JAVA_OPTIONS="-DanalyzerOutput=sdEditRtClient -DsdEditHost=127.0.0.1 -DsdEditPort=60001 -javaagent:jTracert.jar $JAVA_OPTIONS"

**GlassFish V2**

Windows & Linux

File: %DOMAIN_HOME%\config\domain.xml

Search for jvm-options element and add the elements
-DanalyzerOutput=sdEditRtClient 
-DsdEditHost=127.0.0.1 
-DsdEditPort=60001 
-javaagent:jTracert.jar
Start the domain as usual.